# Adding an x axis label with 2 y axis labels

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I can add 2 y-axis to a octave/matlab plot but when I try and add the x-axis at the bottom of the plot with **xlabel('Frequency in Hz')** it doesn't show up

```
[ax h1 h2]=plotyy(xx,yy,xx,yy2); %plot two y axes and 1 x-axis
axes(ax(1)); ylabel('Phase Angle in degrees');
axes(ax(2)); ylabel('Amplitude');
```

Anybody know how to fix this so the x-axis will also show up

I'm using octave 3.2.4 / matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to call `xlabel()` after referencing one of the specific axes on the plot. You just need to do it once, but because of the double axis, invoking x-label outside of a specific axis context won't work. The following works for me just fine in Octave 3.2.4.

```
xx  = [1,2,3]; 
yy  = [10,11,12]; 
yy2 = [-10,-11,-12]; 

[ax h1 h2]=plotyy(xx,yy,xx,yy2); 

axes(ax(1)); xlabel('Frequency in Hz'); ylabel('Phase Angle in degrees');
axes(ax(2)); ylabel('Amplitude');
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a label (either `xlabel` or `ylabel`) to certain axes you can also pass this axes reference as first argument of the command call. This way you will also guarantee that you are on the right context as @EMS pointed out.

```
xx  = [1,2,3]; 
yy  = [10,11,12]; 
yy2 = [-10,-11,-12]; 

[ax h1 h2]=plotyy(xx,yy,xx,yy2); 

xlabel(ax(1),'Frequency in Hz'); ylabel(ax(1),'Phase Angle in degrees');
ylabel(ax(2),'Amplitude');
```

This is also better in terms of performance, as in case you call `axes` several times, you will see how everything slows considerably down.